# Remove left space between ListView border and Items

Tags: android, listview

Can somebody tell me how can I remove the space between the listview border and the items inside the listview?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the layouts you are using that have the `ListView` and for the rows. Or, use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio to try to determine where your padding or margins are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins from your xml listview layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you are not looking for removing space between listview border and items (The red sign on your image says that! you want to remove space between two elements inside 1 item). If that is true, then you have to go to the custom layout file you created to set as a row for the listview. It looks like you have 2 TextViews there ("Go" and "Bro1, Bro2......"). There you have to play with the Margin-Up and Margin-Bottom of these 2 textviews.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
android:layout_marginUp="1dp"
```

If you mean the space around the listview then either check the margins of the listview or paddings of the parent layout of the listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">        

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:orientation="vertical" 
       android:padding="0dp">

       <ListView
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```